# Borders around table cells - CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

With the following table I have some problems. First, what's wrong with the html? I'm getting errors flagged. But the main problem is, that the leftcolumn is not getting a complete border and I cannot figure out why.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4v3pngke/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title> Auflistung 2014</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      * html body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
      }

      body {
        font-family: "Lucida Console", sans-serif;
        font-size: 66%;
      }

      table {
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 0;
        width: 650px;
      }

      td {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: right;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }

      th {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 120%;
      }

      body {
        margin: 10px;
      }

      .linkespalte {
        text-align: center;
        width: 80px;
        font-size: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }

      .lfd {
        width: 3em;
      }

      .bet {
        width: 6em;
      }

      .vorst {
        width: 6em;
      }

      .date {
        width: 6em;
      }

      .mwst {
        width: 4em;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="7"> Ueberschrift I </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Summe Netto: 0.00</td>
        <td colspan="4">Summe Vorsteuer 7%: 0.00 Summe Vorsteuer 19%: 0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="7">Ueberschrift II</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="linkespalte" rowspan="250"><em>480</em></td>
        <td class="lfd"> 1</td>
        <td class="date"> 18.12.</td>
        <td width="120">Fa XY</td>
        <td width="120">iPad AIR 16GB</td>
        <td width="10" class="bet"> 369.00</td>
        <td class="mwst"> 19</td>
        <td class="vorst"> 58.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Summe Netto: 310.08</td>
        <td colspan="4">Summe Vorsteuer 7%: 0.00 Summe Vorsteuer 19%: 58.92</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I'm getting errors flagged." - and what might those be?

Comment: flagged by a validator (like missing charset)?

Comment: Looks like your left column has a border to me - https://jsfiddle.net/0ncer9dd/

Comment: Yes, the left column (class="linkespalte") has a border too. Is it that since every cell has a border that two borders xor-out themselves?

Comment: When looking at the source code in Firefox and switch on W3C validation, I'm getting a couple of errors: 
`line 34 column 20 - Fehler: Table columns in range 2…3 established by element “th” have no cells beginning in them.
`
`line 34 column 20 - Fehler: Table columns in range 5…7 established by element “th” have no cells beginning in them.
`
`line 39 column 43 - Fehler: Table cell spans past the end of its row group established by a “tbody” element; clipped to the end of the row group.
`

Comment: looks like those concerning the obsolete usage of the width tag can be easily overcome by introducing a class .w120 { width:120em;} but the ones with the "have no cells beginning in them" are difficult to me to eliminate, as well as "table cell spans pas the end of its row group".

My actual problem is the missing border at the bottom of the left column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is as below :

```
<td class="linkespalte" rowspan="250" ><em>480</em></td>
```

But, it should be as below :

```
<td class="linkespalte" rowspan="2" ><em>480</em></td>
```

Comment: The problem was that I was generating the tables on the fly from a kind of report generator that could not (easily) know the number of rows beforehand, I just took a large number (250) which I was sure of that it wasn't exceeded by the number of rows right beside the spanning leftcolumn. (a maybe dirty approach - is there some kind of "*" option for this?)

Comment: Funnily setting the row span count right (to 2) also makes the "missing bottom border" problem go away. But a solution without specifying the correct numer of rows to span would be more welcome.